# Virtualhost url not found

Tags: html, apache2, virtualhost

I installed LAMP on a new EC2 server and via the public IP address I can see the default Ubuntu webpage as loaded by my new apache server.

My problems began when I created a new directory, simply called test, alongside the original html directory. In test, I created index.html with the content "Test page responding and loading ...".

So, I then copy `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` to test.conf and set `DocumentRoot /var/www/test`.

I enabled the virtualhost by `sudo a2ensite test.conf` and restarted the server with `sudo service apache2 reload`.

In my browser, when I visit the IP address I get the ubuntu page as loaded by apache. I then append `/test` to the end of the IP address and I get a *Not found: The requested URL /test was not found on this server.* error.

I disabled the `000-default.conf` virtualhost, just out of curiosity, and restarted the server. My output from `test/index.html` loads in a browser using just the IP address - which I did not expect.

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/test

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted

I'm trying to simply serve test/index.html when I visit ***.*.*.*/test** in my browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want Apache to select the default virtual host (the first one for a given host+port) you'll need to use `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` in your added virtual host to make sure it matches the hostname/address you're using in the browser.

`apachectl -S` will summarize your vhosts.